# RestSharp deserialize ampersand

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm a happy user of RestSharp, however I'm having a problem with a rest service returning ampersands in the string. The response is:

`<response>`
`<name>GE Healthcare Austria GmbH & Co OG</name>`
`</response>`

And RestSharp throws an exception because of the **&**

what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the normal behavior. You have to write your own deserializator for restsharp or to replace invalid symbols to use default ones.